# Appending a list to a list

Tags: python, list, append

This is a question for one of my class assignments that I have tried solving for days...1) As you already know, we can have a list within a list in python. This feature enables us to make tables in python using lists. Create a list variable called student_info with the information below.

Name    Color   Lang    Food

Arya    Blue    Python  Sushi

Jon Yellow  C++ Pasta

Sansa   Green   Java    Taco

Bran    Purple  Julia   Pizza

You can start by creating a seperate list for each row of the table by typing the sequence of data points of a row. Create the list by assigning it to a variable named row_1. Now let’s do the same for the other rows and create five lists, one for each row in our dataset. Finally append these rows to the table list called table_list.

In my code I tried this however I am stuck on how I am supposed to append multiple items into table_list. I cannot use for loops. This was my attempt but I keep getting assertion errors. Any help is appreciated.

```py
student_info = ['Name','Color','Lang','Food']
row_1 = ['Arya','Blue','Python','Sushi']
row_2 = ['Jon','Yellow','C++','Pasta']
row_3 = ['Sansa','Green','Java','Taco']
row_4 = ['Bran','Purple','Julia','Pizza']
table_list = []
table_list.extend[row_1, row_2, row_3, row_4 ]
```

Comment: try using .append rather than .extend.

Answer (score 2):

Simply construct the list that you want:

```
table_list = [row_1, row_2, row_3, row_4]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you forget `()` when you use `extend()` function!!!
When you use function in python, don't forget the `()`.

```py
student_info = ['Name','Color','Lang','Food']
row_1 = ['Arya','Blue','Python','Sushi']
row_2 = ['Jon','Yellow','C++','Pasta']
row_3 = ['Sansa','Green','Java','Taco']
row_4 = ['Bran','Purple','Julia','Pizza']
table_list = []
table_list.extend([row_1, row_2, row_3, row_4 ])
```

or just use:

```py
table_list = [row_1, row_2, row_3, row_4 ]
```

then `table_list` become

```
[['Arya', 'Blue', 'Python', 'Sushi'],
 ['Jon', 'Yellow', 'C++', 'Pasta'],
 ['Sansa', 'Green', 'Java', 'Taco'],
 ['Bran', 'Purple', 'Julia', 'Pizza']]
```

Answer (score 1):

The direct problem with your code is that methods/functions use parentheses not brackets. So strictly speaking, the line should be `table_list.extend()` not `table_list.extend[]`.

With that in mind, `.extend()` will add the items of your list (removing the list structure), so you will not get a list of list, but one long list. You need to use `.append()` to get a list of list.

Regardless of the method you use, both `.extend()` and `.append()` only take one argument at a time. Without a for loop, you would have to call `table_list.append(X)`, multiple times (or make X a list of your lists, which would be pointless in this specific scenario).

You can also use the more direct method of making list of lists by using `table_list = [student_info, row_1, row_2, row_3, row_4]`

Answer (score -2):

table_list=row_1+row_2+row_3+row_4

adding should work if you are trying to extend the list

Out[13]:
['Arya',
'Blue',
'Python',
'Sushi',
'Jon',
'Yellow',
'C++',
'Pasta',
'Sansa',
'Green',
'Java',
'Taco',
'Bran',
'Purple',
'Julia',
'Pizza']